# MS Graph API - Access Sharepoint folder that contains spaces or special characters in path

Tags: api, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to access a Sharepoint Online documents library through the Microsoft Graph API.
It works fine until the folder path contains spaces or special characters.

Endpoint prefix is : `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/drives/{drive-id}`

I tried to replace the space character with `%20`, `-`, `_`, `_x0020_`  and `+` with no success.
Also tried to put together the path between quotes just the same way you do in command prompt for space containing paths.

I also noticed that it won't work when the path contains non US-ASCII characters such as `é` `à` `è`  and so on.

That will work :

```
GET /root:/parentfolder/childfolder:/children
```

That won't:

```
GET /root:/parentfolder/folder with spaces:/children

GET /root:/parentfolder/caractères-spéciaux:/children
```

I've been searching over the web with no luck.

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found a solution.
Can navigate through Sharepoint folders with their IDs. Nervermind spaces and non-ASCII chars.

GET `$baseUrl`/v1.0/sites/`$siteId`/drives/`$driveId`/items/`$folderId`/children

Comment: But what if you only have the folder name and don't know the folderId?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can retrieve it by enumerating the parent directory, you shall get some details including folder IDs

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but the issue there would be that I would have to make 4-5 calls to finally get to the folder and then get a list of files in that folder. Because the path to the file is a few folders down, and when I try with the folder path string it doesn't find it. I would have to start at the root and work my way down, each folder down would be another request. Funny how I can make one request to upload the file with the full path string, but I won't know the file name when retrieving because of how our app works, but will know the folders. Thanks for replying.

Comment: I'm sure with lots of hours and trial and error I might finally get a query string that would work, but with spaces it won't. I have fixed the spaces when I upload the file by replacing all spaces with "_"